# Is there a WPF RowDetails functionality for ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, wpf, asp.net-mvc

Im getting started with ASP.NET. I need to let users click on rows of a table and then show them some extra information relating to that row. This is down using RowDetails templates in WPF. I am wondering is there anything similar for ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `Repeater` with a `Table`, and make it so each `RepeaterItem` is two table rows. Make the 2nd row hidden, and the 1st row toggle the 2nd one's visibility when clicked on.

I don't remember the exact syntax, but it looks something like this:

```
<asp:Repeater>
    <HeaderTemplate><table></HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>

        <tr click="javascript: ToggleNextRow(this);">
           <td><%# Eval("Id") %></td>
           <td><%# Eval("Name") %></td>
           <td><%# Eval("Description") %></td>
        </tr>


        <tr style="display: none;">
           <td colspan="3"><%# Eval("Details") %></td>
        </tr>

    </ItemTemplate>

    <FooterTemplate></table></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```